# Filtrando por data com dataTables como fazer - descomplicando

Tags: data, table, filter

Olá!

Estou implementando o filtro por data com jquery dataTable, com o recurso draw() incorporado. Está um pouco complicado então gostaria de ver se alguém consegue compreender.

Coloquei o código no fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8bnLwu47/12/

Vou colocar aqui o trecho do js que estou trabalhando:

```
table = $('.table_master').DataTable({
      paging: false,
      info: false
    });

    // Extend dataTables search
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#min-date').val();
        var max = $('#max-date').val();
        var createdAt = data[1] || 0; // Our date column in the table

        if (
              (min == "" || max == "") ||
              (moment(createdAt).isSameOrAfter(min) && moment(createdAt).isSameOrBefore(max))
        ){

          return true;

        }

            return false;
            //table.draw();

      }
    );

    $('.date-range-filter').change(function() {     
        table.draw();
    });
```

A idéia é fazer uma espécie de between com o filtro, escolhendo uma data inicial e uma data final, obtendo todos os resultados nesse intervalo. Por exemplo, se tenho as datas: "01/06/2018","02/06/2018","03/06/2018","04/06/2018", Então ao filtrar de 01/06/2018 à 03/06/2018, a tabela deve mostrar os 3 registros no intervalo, 01,02 e 03.

Com o código atual, ainda não tenho esse resultado, o filtro não acontece... gostaria de ver se alguem sabe como implementar. 
No fiddle já coloquei as bibliotecas jquery, dataTables e moment.js que são necessárias...

Comment: Reforçando a idéia, a necessidade está em realizar o filtro com jquery, onde o .draw() é referenciado pelo recurso, tendo como base a coluna de data presente na tabela.

Comment: Nesse caso o filtro através dos inputs, definindo data inicial e data final, ocorreria sem a necessidade de consulta ao BD...

Comment: Olá, alguém saberia uma forma para conseguir realizar o filtro no dataTables com esse formato? https://jsfiddle.net/8bnLwu47/12/